# Google maps sdk callout issue ios6

Tags: ios6, google-maps-sdk-ios

i am using googlemap sdk for ios 6 in my project
The problem i am facing is with Marker options

```
GMSMarkerOptions *londonOptions = [[GMSMarkerOptions alloc] init];
londonOptions.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.500,-0.127);
londonOptions.title = nil;
londonOptions.snippet = nil;
[mapView_ addMarkerWithOptions:londonOptions];
```

Google states that if i set the title and snippet to nil then the marker would not show a callout if i tap on it.

but it does show an callout on tapping on it.

Has anyone faced this problem
Thanks in advance
Regards
Nitesh

Comment: I just created a map and used your code and tapped on the marker and the no InfoWindow appears. Are you sure you are using the latest version (1.1.1) of the SDK?

Comment: thats strange! I am using 1.1.0. il update the sdk and check.

Comment: The fix to not show the InfoWindow was added in 1.1.1 :)

Answer (score 0):

I worked around it by returning an empty uiview :) but as share said, it is fixed now